# creating a square 2d array in java with only one user input for row and column

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I have a problem with 2dimensional arrays in java. I need to write a program that reads a number (d - the number of columns AND rows in the array). The array is supposed to be a square filled with numbers from 0 to (eg)35 if the number d=6.

so, the number d tells us how many numbers to get in one row and one column. I've been searching for an answer for quite some time and can't seem to find it - how do I write this program with only one input? Every other example I've seen consists of two user inputs [row][column]. But my assignment specifically states that the user only needs to input one number.

Also, how do I arrange the numbers correctly based on this user input number d?

Thankyou:)

Comment: Surely row = column = input?

Comment: You don't need 2 inputs for this problem, because the first input tells you all you need to know. The first input tells you both the number of rows and the number of columns as well, because it's a **square** array.

Answer (score 0):

ill give you a not so much code example:
`Scanner` for user input. User input is d. now initialize the array `int[][]numbers=new int[d][d]`(as you can see just use d for column and row). now you can fill the array with 2 for-loops

```
 int counter=0;
    for(int i=0;i<d;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<d;j++){
            array[i][j]=counter;
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

if the array isn't looking as you want it just switch i and j here `array[i][j]= counter;`

Comment: okay, but why are i and j >d? aren't they supposed to be smaller?

Comment: yup. was my mistake. fixed it

Comment: just one more question. Does this represent the actual array with numbers from 0 to something or is it just kind of a frame that needs to be filled?

Comment: the array is filled with the ints from 0 to 35 it d is 6

Comment: ok, so inside of these two for loops goes everything else I want to put into it right? Thankyou :)

Comment: you can change the counter to anything of type int. if you want to have another type like string you have to change the type of the array too